# Subtracting two dates with Robot Framework

Tags: datetime, time, robotframework, subtraction

I have this following example where two dates are substracted using Robot Framework.
This example below works with no problem.

```
*** Settings ***
Library           DateTime

*** Variables ***
${date1}    13.04.2021 19:40:22
${date2}    13.04.2021 19:33:33

*** Keywords ***
Subtract Two Dates
    ${diff}=    Subtract Date From Date  ${date1}  ${date2}  date1_format=%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S  date2_format=%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S

*** Test Cases ***
TC01
    Subtract Two Dates
```

However in the actual substracting I am trying to, dates would be presented as:

```
${date1}    4/13/21, 19:40:22 PM 
${date2}    4/13/21, 19:33:33 PM
```

How should I modify date1_format and date2_format to achieve substraction with a format like above?

I have tried to look at DateTime library documentation and searching for various examples with no success.

Answer (score 1):

- First of all there is no 19 in en_US date representation. Dates should without PM/AM or 9:40:22 PM
- Second, if you subtract AM from PM you get wrong results.

Here is correct example

```
*** Settings ***
Library  DateTime

*** Variables ***
${date1}    4/13/21, 9:40:22 PM
${date2}    4/13/21, 9:33:33 AM

*** Test Cases ***
Date Test
  ${diff}=  Subtract Date From Date  ${date1}  ${date2}  date1_format=%m/%d/%y, %I:%M:%S %p  date2_format=%m/%d/%y, %I:%M:%S %p  result_format=compact
  Log To Console  Difference: ${diff}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that I got this working like this:

```
*** Settings ***
Library           DateTime

*** Variables ***
${date1}    13.04.2021 19:40:22
${date2}    13.04.2021 19:33:33

${date1_modified}    4/13/21, 19:40:22 PM
${date2_modified}    4/13/21, 19:33:33 PM

*** Keywords ***
Subtract Two Dates
    ${diff}=    Subtract Date From Date  ${date1_modified}  ${date2_modified}  date1_format=%m/%d/%y, %H:%M:%S PM  date2_format=%m/%d/%y, %H:%M:%S PM

*** Test Cases ***
TC01
    Subtract Two Dates
```

So the correct date_format to use for these example dates I was searching for was `%m/%d/%y, %H:%M:%S PM`